# How to get the handle of a registry key without even read permission

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I'm trying to call this function to take owner for a key.

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public extern static int SetSecurityInfo(IntPtr hKeySrc, SE_OBJECT_TYPE lpSubKey, SECURITY_INFORMATION securityInfo, IntPtr psidOwner, IntPtr psidGroup, IntPtr pDacl, IntPtr pSacl);
```

However, to call this function, I first need a handle to the key (IntPtr hKeysrc). Before I use these function to get the handle.

```
RegistryKey key = root.OpenSubKey(keyName);

private static IntPtr GetRegistryKeyHandle(RegistryKey registryKey)
    {
        IntPtr ret = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            Type registryKeyType = typeof(RegistryKey);

            System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo =
            registryKeyType.GetField("hkey", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            SafeHandle handle = (SafeHandle) fieldInfo.GetValue(registryKey);
            ret = handle.DangerousGetHandle();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError("GetRegistryKeyHandle ERROR:" + ex.ToString());
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

But now the key that I'm targeting only has permission to System account!

When I try to open permissions in regedit for the key, I get the error
**You do not have permission to view the current permission settings, but you can make permission changes.**

I don't even have read permission to the key. Then the method I used to get handle will failed with unauthorized error.

***How can I get a handle to the key in this case?*** Actually, regedit can do it. So I think there may an API can do it. But I don't know which API to call.

Comment: To do this the nice way, you need to enable SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege and then open the key for WRITE_OWNER access.  I don't know if there's a .NET API that allows you to select the access mode, but you should be able to p/invoke RegOpenKeyEx if necessary.

Comment: Alternatively, if you enable backup and restore privilege, that tells Windows to ignore the current permissions, so you don't need to do anything special when opening the key.

Comment: "Actually, regedit can do it." Nope, regedit cannot get a handle to the key either; that's why it did not show you the current permission settings.

Comment: @RaymondChen: more precisely, that means it couldn't get a handle to the key *with READ_CONTROL access*. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HarryJohnston got the right solution.

1. Enable SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
2. Open the key for WRITE_OWNER access